# Python - Read a table column on a specific page of a PDF on the browser as a NumPy Array

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping

## Task

On page 10 of [this](https://cdn.who.int/media/docs/default-source/gho-documents/global-health-estimates/gpe_discussion_paper_series_paper31_2001_age_standardization_rates.pdf) PDF there is Table 1. I would like to read the column "WHO World Standard*" as a NumPy array.

## (Failed) Attempts

1. Tabula raises a `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` error.

   ```
   import tabula
   pdf = "https://cdn.who.int/media/docs/default-source/gho-documents/global-health-estimates/gpe_discussion_paper_series_paper31_2001_age_standardization_rates.pdf"
   tables = tabula.read_pdf(pdf, pages=10)
   ```
2. PDFPlumber cannot find the URL/PDF

   ```
   import pdfplumber


   with pdfplumber.open("https://cdn.who.int/media/docs/default-source/gho-documents/global-health-estimates/gpe_discussion_paper_series_paper31_2001_age_standardization_rates.pdf") as pdf:
      page = pdf.pages[9]
      table = page.extract_table()
      header_row = table[0]
      who_std_col_idx = header_row.index("WHO World Standard*")
      who_std_values = [row[who_std_col_idx] for row in table[1:]]
      print(who_std_values)
   ```

## Bonus

Even better if it can be done exclusively using Python packages available in Conda, as ideally I would like to create a `requirements.txt` for my project.

Answer (score 1):

You can try making a [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) and pass it to [`read_pdf`](https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html#tabula.io.read_pdf), then do some *post-processing*:

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO

URL = "https://cdn.who.int/.../...aper31_2001_age_standardization_rates.pdf"

PN = 10 # page number
TN = 1  # table number 
CN = -1 # last col / "WHO World Standard*"

arr = (
    pd.to_numeric(
        tabula.read_pdf(BytesIO(requests.get(URL).content), pages=PN)[TN-1]
        .iloc[1:, CN].str.split(expand=True).iloc[:, CN],
        errors="coerce",
    ).dropna().to_numpy()[:-1]
)
```

Or with [pymupdf](/questions/tagged/pymupdf), using the same logic :

```
import fitz # pip install pymupdf

with fitz.open(stream=requests.get(URL).content) as pdf:
    arr = (
        pd.to_numeric(
            pdf[PN-1].find_tables()[TN-1].to_pandas().iloc[:, CN],
            errors="coerce",
        ).dropna().to_numpy()[:-1]
    )
```

Output :

```
array([8.86, 8.69, 8.6 , 8.47, 8.22, 7.93, 7.61, 7.15, 6.59, 6.04, 5.37,
       4.55, 3.72, 2.96, 2.21, 1.52, 0.91, 0.63])
```

Answer (score 1):

Camelot appears to work perfectly:

```py
import camelot
tables = camelot.read_pdf('https://cdn.who.int/...', pages='10')
df = tables[0].df
```

This creates a pandas DataFrame, which will need a little bit of topping and tailing.

Comment: OP seems to ask for a NumPy array. Can you go ahead and do what you call *a bit of topping and tailing* ?

Comment: I downloaded camelot (brew install ghostscript tcl-tk)
However, I cant seem to import it on my file. Any suggestions how to get around it?

Comment: Did you pip install camelot-py? https://pypi.org/project/camelot-py/